# UWP saving and retrieving storagefile from a database

Tags: sqlite, win-universal-app, bitmapimage, storagefile

I want to save and retrieve StorageFile and bitmap images into Sqlite database. 
and then retrieve them later on. and bitmapimage will be from thumbnail of that file. thnks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have already told saving StorageFile and BitMapIamge to database is not a good idea. Database might choke if image file is big. Instead save path of image to db. You can load image using Path like this

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(   "ms-appx:///Assets/WorldCupFlags/Sri_Lanka.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

And StorageFile you can't store it to database.

Comment: haha yeah this question was asked b4 u answered it on my other question :) thankyou again

Comment: and actually the bitmap image I wanna store is a thumbnail of that storage file, so where can i save the thumbnail so that i dnt have to retrieve it again?

Comment: also can i have ur twitter?

Comment: You can save in Application Folder. And save that path in db.